# On extension field

Tags: extension-field, splitting-field

I have confusion on terminologies and results on extension field.

1. If an extension field E  is splitting field F as well as separable extension of F, Then (my doubt is), it is normal extension(from Fraleigh's book) it is Galois extension (on internet sources) also on internet these normal and halos extensions are distinct.
   (Normal is defined same as splitting field some places).
2. {E:F}=|G(E/F)|  is necessary or sufficient (which ) condition for being splitting field. 
   In Fraleigh's book it is necessary only, what about converse( i have no idea)
3. {E:F}=|G(E/F)| =[E:F], is necessary or sufficient (which ) condition for being galois extension

Comment: There are several things to show : splitting field implies normal (all minimal polynomials split completely), generated by separable elements implies all minimal polynomials are separable, for a separable extension $[E:F] = |Hom_F(E,\overline{E})|$, normal implies $Hom_F(E,\overline{E})= Aut(E/F)$,  normal and separable implies $[E:F] = |Aut(E/F)|$ as well as $F= E^{Aut(E/F)}$ (the fixed subfield) which implies $a$'s minimal polynomial is $\prod_{b \in Aut(E/F)a} (X-b)$ all those conditions being what we really mean with Galois.

Comment: From this i am getting, Galois extension and normal are different, Galois extension iff all 3 numbers associated are equal.

Comment: Galois is defined as normal and separable because they imply what I have listed